# Use string in function parameter to get JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm trying to figure out how to make a function that takes an input then uses it to grab a specific JSON object.

My data is in `rpcData` but I want the input from the `obj` function parameter to expand on this.

For example `obj = ".market_data.current_price.usd"` which would then be appended to `JSON.stringify(rpcData)` making it `JSON.stringify(rpcData.market_data.current_price.usd)`

```
export const Blockchain = ({ path, obj }) => {
  const { rpcData, isLoading, isError } = fetchRPC(path);
  if (isLoading) return <Loading />;
  if (isError) return <Error />;
  return JSON.stringify(rpcData);
};
```

Using one of the answers from here I was able to get it to work up to one level deep with `JSON.stringify(rpcData[obj])` when `obj="height"` but still can't get it to work with deeper nested objects.

Comment: Seems like you want something like `return JSON.stringify(rpcData.result[obj]);`. But your question is not asked very clearly.

Comment: I can't understand exactly the problem you're facing, can you please elaborate on it?
What is the desired output?

Comment: @Marc This is it, thanks. I'm a beginner and also not a very good communicator lol. I'll try to make the question more clear for anyone that finds this.